# NodeJS plugin in IntelliJ Community Edition does not work

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea

I have tried to use the NodeJS plugin in IntelliJ IDEA CE but can't get it to work. After the plugin have been installed and the IDE restarts, it says that it can't find Javascript plugin which is said to be required by NodeJS (though it doesn't say so in the documentation).

Does NodeJS plugin only work in the licensed edition of IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[NodeJS plug-in](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?idea&pluginId=6098) requires IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate as it depends on JavaScript plug-in available only in the commercial edition.

It also works in WebStorm, PhpStorm, RubyMine and PyCharm products.

Comment: This is a bit frustrating. Nowhere on this page does it say that you need Ultimate edition:   
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/nodejs.html   
Does PyCharm community support it, do you know?

Comment: Sorry, PyCharm Community Edition doesn't support it.

Comment: Here is a simple workaround for running javascript apps in intellij community edition.
Create a runapp.bat or runapp.sh. Add below command in the script
npm run build && npm run start. Add run configuration and choose shell script. Point the .bat or .sh file depending on your OS. That's it

Answer (score 7):

Node.js is listed in the frameworks that are supported only in Ultimate version.

This list is provided in Intellij's features (comparing Ultimate vs Community editions):

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html

Comment: Link only answers are not quite recommended. Please provide some explanation.