# Odoo Mac OSX installation get error "Could not execute command lessc" in PyCharm Community Edition

Tags: node.js, macos, less, pycharm, odoo-9

I installed Odoo 9 on Mac OSX using Homebrew virtual environment.
I installed npm, less and less-plugin-clean-css.

Finally if I launch Odoo from the Mac Terminal, using the appropriate parameters, everything goes well and I can enter my odoo with localhost:8069.

I then setup PyCharm Community Edition for odoo development, but when I run odoo from within PyCharm I get the error:

```
"Could not execute command lessc"
```

and obviously the web layout is totally wrong.

I saw here [NodeJS plugin in IntelliJ Community Edition does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13625565/nodejs-plugin-in-intellij-community-edition-does-not-work?lq=1) that you cannot use NodeJS plugin with PyCharm CE.

My question then is: "How to enable PyCharm CE to use less and get rid of the error?".

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: Up to now no. Surely you cannot use PyCharm Community, but also with PyCharm pro I need to work through some tricky setting. I will update when I solve.

Comment: were you able to solve the problem? I am facing it now. Runs with terminal but not in pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Pycharm in getting error `Could not execute command lessc`  and you have installed less which you can check by entering lessc command in terminal

Fix:

1. If you are using virtualenv then activate virtualenv from terminal and restart the server again from **terminal**, this time it won't give any error.
2. If you are not using virutalenv then you can just run from **terminal** server without any problems

I'm not sure why this problem is specific to PyCharm.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue from PyCharm Professional, but I solve this issue with this  way

When i finish installing the PyCharm pro ,then i set the environment variables in the 'run/debug configuraition'

`(/usr/loca/bin)
which value(path) i found  is using command "which lessc" in the terminal`

Then I think the PyCharm can find lessc, and finnally I get rid of this nightmare

`Could not execute command 'lessc'

Answer (score 0):

For me, updating the node was the solution. It was version 0.10.33. Now it's 6.1.12.

Answer (score -1):

Check out this answer.  You must uninstall node and reinstall it in a certain order:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36395799?noredirect=1

At least that is what worked for me.