# Odoo Installation on Mac Could Not Execute Command LESSC

Tags: python, macos, postgresql, odoo

So I have a mac running 10.11.4 (El Capitan).

I followed this tutorial: http://kiattipong.blogspot.com/2015/05/setup-odoo-development-on-os-x-with.html?showComment=1459570104589.  Actually the issues I had I posted in the comments section in this blog as well.

Everything went smoothly up to about the requirements part where I got some installation errors (file not found).  When I tried to run python ./odoo.py I would get missing module errors.  So I manually installed some using pip install ( psycopg2, reportlab, dateultil, passlib, psutil, requests) and finally I got the odoo server running.  But when I tried localhost:8069 I kept getting internal server error.

---

I was having this issue below where I thought the misconfiguration of the postgresql db was causing the problem where my odoo loaded without html and css formatting.  Then all of a sudden it worked, i created a dbname and password but now I get this screen:

[image: Broken Formatting and LESSC error]

Here is the latest stack trace for the LESSC error:

```
(odoo-env) Marcios-MacBook-Air:~ quique123$ cd odoo
(odoo-env) Marcios-MacBook-Air:odoo quique123$ python ./odoo.py
2016-04-02 16:28:03,335 544 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP version 9.0c
2016-04-02 16:28:03,335 544 INFO ? openerp: addons paths: ['/Users/quique123/Library/Application Support/Odoo/addons/9.0', u'/Users/quique123/odoo/openerp/addons', u'/Users/quique123/odoo/addons']
2016-04-02 16:28:03,336 544 INFO ? openerp: database: default@default:default
2016-04-02 16:28:03,630 544 INFO ? openerp.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on 0.0.0.0:8069
2016-04-02 16:30:06,356 544 INFO ? openerp.addons.bus.models.bus: Bus.loop listen imbus on db postgres
2016-04-02 16:30:07,381 544 INFO ? openerp.addons.report.models.report: You need Wkhtmltopdf to print a pdf version of the reports.
2016-04-02 16:30:07,787 544 INFO ? openerp.http: HTTP Configuring static files
2016-04-02 16:30:07,938 544 INFO santiapps openerp.modules.loading: loading 1 modules...
2016-04-02 16:30:07,955 544 INFO santiapps openerp.modules.loading: 1 modules loaded in 0.02s, 0 queries
2016-04-02 16:30:08,025 544 INFO santiapps openerp.modules.loading: loading 28 modules...
2016-04-02 16:30:08,122 544 INFO santiapps openerp.modules.loading: 28 modules loaded in 0.10s, 0 queries
2016-04-02 16:30:08,578 544 INFO santiapps openerp.modules.loading: Modules loaded.
2016-04-02 16:30:08,580 544 INFO santiapps openerp.addons.base.ir.ir_http: Generating routing map
2016-04-02 16:30:09,466 544 ERROR santiapps openerp.addons.base.ir.ir_qweb: Could not execute command 'lessc'
2016-04-02 16:30:09,827 544 ERROR santiapps openerp.addons.base.ir.ir_qweb: Could not execute command 'lessc'
2016-04-02 16:30:10,000 544 INFO santiapps werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2016 16:30:09] "GET /web HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2016-04-02 16:30:12,110 544 ERROR santiapps openerp.addons.base.ir.ir_qweb: Could not execute command 'lessc'
2016-04-02 16:30:12,155 544 ERROR santiapps openerp.addons.base.ir.ir_qweb: Could not execute command 'lessc'
2016-04-02 16:30:12,185 544 ERROR santiapps openerp.addons.base.ir.ir_qweb: Could not execute command 'lessc'
2016-04-02 16:30:12,226 544 ERROR santiapps openerp.addons.base.ir.ir_qweb: Could not execute command 'lessc'
2016-04-02 16:30:12,239 544 ERROR santiapps openerp.addons.base.ir.ir_qweb: Could not execute command 'lessc'
2016-04-02 16:30:12,419 544 ERROR santiapps openerp.addons.base.ir.ir_qweb: Could not execute command 'lessc'
2016-04-02 16:30:12,630 544 ERROR santiapps openerp.addons.base.ir.ir_qweb: Could not execute command 'lessc'
2016-04-02 16:30:12,647 544 ERROR santiapps openerp.addons.base.ir.ir_qweb: Could not execute command 'lessc'
2016-04-02 16:30:12,651 544 ERROR santiapps openerp.addons.base.ir.ir_qweb: Could not execute command 'lessc'
2016-04-02 16:30:12,711 544 ERROR santiapps openerp.addons.base.ir.ir_qweb: Could not execute command 'lessc'
2016-04-02 16:30:12,729 544 ERROR santiapps openerp.addons.base.ir.ir_qweb: Could not execute command 'lessc'
2016-04-02 16:30:12,742 544 ERROR santiapps openerp.addons.base.ir.ir_qweb: Could not execute command 'lessc'
2016-04-02 16:30:15,829 544 ERROR santiapps openerp.addons.base.ir.ir_qweb: Could not execute command 'lessc'
2016-04-02 16:30:15,836 544 ERROR santiapps openerp.addons.base.ir.ir_qweb: Could not execute command 'lessc'
2016-04-02 16:30:15,837 544 ERROR santiapps openerp.addons.base.ir.ir_qweb: Could not execute command 'lessc'
2016-04-02 16:30:15,921 544 ERROR santiapps openerp.addons.base.ir.ir_qweb: Could not execute command 'lessc'
2016-04-02 16:30:15,923 544 ERROR santiapps openerp.addons.base.ir.ir_qweb: Could not execute command 'lessc'
2016-04-02 16:30:15,951 544 ERROR santiapps openerp.addons.base.ir.ir_qweb: Could not execute command 'lessc'
```

---

### NO NEED TO READ BELOW UNLESS YOU THINK IT MIGHT BE A DB ERROR

First I remember trying to create a user using this command:

```
sudo su - postgres -c "createuser -s $USER"
```

which I translated to:

```
sudo su - postgres -c "createuser -s $quique123"
```

But still Internal Server Error.  I did this because I found that that was caused by a db not being configured properly.  As I kept researching about odoo installation db config issues I found I then needed to modify the conf file to enter the right user credentials.  So I went into my odoo/debian/ (within my virtualenv) and modified the opernerp-server.conf to this:

```
admin_passwd = admin
db_host = localhost
db_port = 8069
db_user = $quique123
db_password = False
```

Its confusing because in my cd I have:

/odoo
/odoo-env

And inside /odoo I have:

/debian
/openerp
/openerp-server
and other folders

Then inside /debian is the openerp-server.conf I've modified.

Now when I open localhost:8069 I do get the page to create the db or retore or backup, but no html/css formatting, just white background and black unformatted letters, broken image icon on top left and all the textfields and dropdowns.
But if I look in the terminal then I get this:

```
    **(odoo-env) Marcios-MacBook-Air:odoo quique123$ python ./odoo.py
2016-04-02 12:22:17,541 574 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP version 9.0c
2016-04-02 12:22:17,541 574 INFO ? openerp: addons paths: ['/Users/quique123/Library/Application Support/Odoo/addons/9.0', u'/Users/quique123/odoo/openerp/addons', u'/Users/quique123/odoo/addons']
2016-04-02 12:22:17,542 574 INFO ? openerp: database: default@default:default
2016-04-02 12:22:17,804 574 INFO ? openerp.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on 0.0.0.0:8069**
2016-04-02 12:23:22,910 574 INFO ? openerp.addons.bus.models.bus: Bus.loop listen imbus on db postgres
2016-04-02 12:23:22,997 574 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2016 12:23:22] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
2016-04-02 12:23:23,007 574 ERROR ? werkzeug: Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/quique123/odoo-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 177, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/Users/quique123/odoo-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 165, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/quique123/odoo/openerp/service/server.py", line 245, in app
    return self.app(e, s)
  File "/Users/quique123/odoo/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 184, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/quique123/odoo/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 170, in application_unproxied
    result = handler(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/quique123/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1487, in __call__
    self.load_addons()
  File "/Users/quique123/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1508, in load_addons
    m = __import__('openerp.addons.' + module)
  File "/Users/quique123/odoo/openerp/modules/module.py", line 61, in load_module
    mod = imp.load_module('openerp.addons.' + module_part, f, path, descr)
  File "/Users/quique123/odoo/addons/document/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    import models
  File "/Users/quique123/odoo/addons/document/models/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    import ir_attachment
  File "/Users/quique123/odoo/addons/document/models/ir_attachment.py", line 8, in <module>
    import pyPdf
ImportError: No module named pyPdf
2016-04-02 12:23:23,212 574 INFO ? openerp.http: Generating nondb routing
2016-04-02 12:23:23,228 574 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2016 12:23:23] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2016-04-02 12:23:26,490 574 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2016 12:23:26] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2016-04-02 12:23:26,538 574 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2016 12:23:26] "GET /web HTTP/1.1" 303 -
2016-04-02 12:23:26,586 574 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2016 12:23:26] "GET /web/database/selector HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2016-04-02 12:23:26,641 574 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2016 12:23:26] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/modal.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2016-04-02 12:23:26,643 574 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2016 12:23:26] "GET /web/static/lib/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2016-04-02 12:23:26,646 574 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2016 12:23:26] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2016-04-02 12:23:26,648 574 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2016 12:23:26] "GET /web/static/lib/jquery/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2016-04-02 12:23:26,649 574 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2016 12:23:26] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/tooltip.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2016-04-02 12:23:26,651 574 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2016 12:23:26] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/dropdown.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2016-04-02 12:23:26,663 574 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2016 12:23:26] "GET /web/static/src/img/logo2.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2016-04-02 12:23:26,966 574 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2016 12:23:26] "GET /web/static/src/img/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2016-04-02 12:24:18,834 574 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2016 12:24:18] "GET /web/database/selector HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2016-04-02 12:24:18,889 574 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2016 12:24:18] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/dropdown.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2016-04-02 12:24:18,891 574 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2016 12:24:18] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/tooltip.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2016-04-02 12:24:18,894 574 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2016 12:24:18] "GET /web/static/lib/jquery/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2016-04-02 12:24:18,894 574 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2016 12:24:18] "GET /web/static/lib/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2016-04-02 12:24:18,899 574 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2016 12:24:18] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2016-04-02 12:24:18,899 574 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2016 12:24:18] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/modal.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2016-04-02 12:24:18,911 574 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2016 12:24:18] "GET /web/static/src/img/logo2.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2016-04-02 12:39:31,759 574 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2016 12:39:31] "GET /web/database/selector HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2016-04-02 12:39:31,815 574 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2016 12:39:31] "GET /web/static/lib/jquery/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2016-04-02 12:39:31,818 574 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2016 12:39:31] "GET /web/static/lib/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2016-04-02 12:39:31,821 574 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2016 12:39:31] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/tooltip.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2016-04-02 12:39:31,826 574 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2016 12:39:31] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/dropdown.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2016-04-02 12:39:31,826 574 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2016 12:39:31] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/js/modal.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2016-04-02 12:39:31,829 574 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2016 12:39:31] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2016-04-02 12:39:31,838 574 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2016 12:39:31] "GET /web/static/src/img/logo2.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seems it was a node/npm issue.  I had installed the node.js package which brings npm.  I googled and found that there were issues if npm was installed without first removing an older version of it?

> https://gist.github.com/DanHerbert/9520689

Somewhere I found this command:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
```

I removed npm and then reinstalled but this time I installed node from brew:

```
brew install node
```

Then I was able to follow the section here on lessc error and Odoo seems to be running fine:

> http://jingigirl.blogspot.com/2015/10/install-odoo-90-on-mac.html

In this post it states that one must instal less and then less-plugin-clean-css and finally upgrade node which in my case wasnt necessary because I already had node 5.10.0.

What led me to the issue was that even after installing the node.js from nodejs.org, when I entered node -v I received an error node not installed!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the stack trace of the error message you posted, you are missing the pyPdf package (unrelated to the database).

This could be generating some loading issues.

Run

```
pip install pyPdf
```

and check if the problem still persists.
If so, post the stack trace.

Comment: Ok I installed it but I still get a bunch of "Could not execute command lessc" errors =  2016-04-02 16:30:28,948 544 ERROR santiapps openerp.addons.base.ir.ir_qweb: Could not execute command 'lessc'

Comment: can you post the full stack trace ?

Comment: Ok I posted the error in the OP, its the first code block.

Comment: Got it!  I think it was a node/npm issue.  I had installed the node.js package which brings npm.  I googled and found that there were issues if npm was installed without first removing an older version of it?  Not sure, but anyway, I removeed npm and then reinstalled it.  Ill post the answer below.  Then I was able to follow the section here on lessc error and Odoo seems to be running fine.  http://jingigirl.blogspot.com/2015/10/install-odoo-90-on-mac.html

Comment: Exactly what I was going to suggest, glad to hear it works. Enjoy !

Answer (score 1):

**Lessc install**

This error occurs almost every time with a fresh installation of Odoo.
(Especially with Ubuntu 12.04)

> 1. First run these three commands in your terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
```

> 2. Then you install nodejs:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

> 3. You can then check version of nodejs using:

```
node -v
```

> 4. It should be at least greater than > **0.10**

```
npm -v
```

Should return a version at least > **1.4**

> 5. Then finally execute the following command, whick will update npm to a newer version as well as install the less plugin:

```
sudo npm install -g npm
sudo npm install -g less less-plugin-clean-css
```

**pypdf for the second error**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-pypdf
```

Comment: Thanks!  I dont have apt though.  But I got it working.