# PyCharm can't execute lessc command in MacOS Sierra but terminal does

Tags: node.js, less, odoo, pycharm

I am trying to run odoo by using PyCharm for development purpose. But PyCharm can't run `lessc` command.

When I run odoo from terminal using following command:

```
python openerp-server -c openerp-server.conf
```

It works perfectly without any lessc error.

When I try to run it from PyCharm with virtualenv it shows:

```
can't execute lessc command
```

I have tried reinstalling node/npm, less, less-plugin-clean-css but nothing works. How can I resolve this problem for PyCharm?

Comment: Try launching PyCharm itself from terminal -- will it be any better?

Comment: No. When I ran it without using virtualenv it worked, no lessc error. I am not sure if virtualenv needs any privilege to execute lessc command.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36376273/783119 perhaps? No other proper ideas :( P.S. By "launching from terminal I meant something like this: `open -a /Applications/PyCharm.app/`

Comment: Yes, I saw that but no luck. About launching from terminal, I understood that. But the problem is not that. If I select Mac Default Python 2.7.* as project interpreter odoo works without any error. If I use python virtualenv then there is 'lessc' command error.  Note that, virtualenv python version is also compatible.